# Automatic page refresh not happening so call refresh again - Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript

I have a page which will automatically get refreshed after 5 mins and will load all the contents. In certain scenario, it seems page is not getting refreshed. So I need to write a function to check whether page is refreshed after 5 mins, if not I need to refresh the page again.

```
<script>

   window.onload = function(e) {

   //alert("before refresh");
   setTimeout("location.reload();", 300000);

   // Firefox || IE
   e = e || window.event;
   var y = e.pageY || e.clientY;


   if(y < 0)  
    alert("Window closed");
   else 
    alert("Window refreshed");

    }
</script>
```

In the above page refresh is happening after 5 mins. But I need to write code for negative scenario (if page refresh not happening after 5 mins, call refresh again).

Your input and suggestions will be very helpful to me. 
    Thanks.

Comment: what about using a cookie to trace refreshes?

Comment: Why is the refresh failing? You should fix the original problem instead of trying to make a hack workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Why not refresh it every 5 minutes? Simply has to write a function that executes after 5 minutes, after first initialization!

```
(function () {  
  window.nsAutoRefreshTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
     clear(window.nsAutoRefreshTimeout)
     window.location.reload()
  }, 300000)
}())
```

Just think about it, the page loads, the counter starts, after 5 minutes it reloads again. The script will start over again! Minimal effort.

*The user may disable javascript though!

You can also do in an old school way. Refreshes every 5m:

*The user may disable this feature on his browser

Comment: Thanks. Currently refresh is happening every 5 mins. Assume there are 100 users, one user is complaining that refresh has not happened so the alerts are not coming. So to fix that problem, we thought that we will capture whether refresh happened or not, if not means then call refresh again. 
If our approach is wrong. Please suggest alternate approaches.
Thanks again for your time. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: updated the answer. but in any case it might be disabled...javascript or the html feature... so..yeah